# Unknown column in where clause - Bad SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'm receiving an error when querying a MySQL database:

Unknown column 'velvet' in 'where clause'

```
"SELECT ATCOCode,Latitude,Longitude FROM StopCode 
INNER JOIN JourneyStopCode ON StopCode.ATCOCode = JourneyStopCode.StopCode 
INNER JOIN Journey On Journey.Code = JourneyStopCode.JourneyCode 
WHERE JourneyCode = code 
AND Journey.Operator = velvet"
```

Is there anything wrong with my SQL? Below is my table structure.

```
---------------        ---------------------         ----------------
|  Journey    |        | JourneyStopCode   |         |  StopCode    |
---------------        ---------------------         ----------------
| Code        |        | JourneyStopCodeID |         |  StopCode    |
| Operator    |        | JourneyCode       |         |  Latitude    |
| Description |        | StopCode          |         |  Longitude   |
---------------        ---------------------         ----------------
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry I should have said, I will edit the question. A MySQL database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to encapsulate the variable into a string I believe.

```
SELECT ATCOCode,Latitude,Longitude FROM StopCode 
INNER JOIN JourneyStopCode ON StopCode.ATCOCode = JourneyStopCode.StopCode 
INNER JOIN Journey On Journey.Code = JourneyStopCode.JourneyCode 
WHERE JourneyCode = 'code'
AND Journey.Operator = 'velvet'
```

Comment: Ahh fantastic. It's clearly been a long day, thanks so much! :)

Comment: I agree, today has been unrealistically slow! Good luck with the rest!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"SELECT ATCOCode,Latitude,Longitude FROM StopCode 
INNER JOIN JourneyStopCode ON StopCode.ATCOCode = JourneyStopCode.StopCode 
INNER JOIN Journey On Journey.Code = JourneyStopCode.JourneyCode 
WHERE JourneyCode = code 
AND Journey.Operator = 'velvet'"
```